# Environment variable set in base test class is not available in derived test classes

Tags: c#, automation, nunit

I have a base test class in which I set the environment variable called ENVIRONMENT:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

internal abstract class BaseTestClass
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void InitializeBaseSuite()
    {
        System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT", "MyValue");
    }
}
```

And in derived test I initialize some class called `TestTasks` that internally reads this variable to know which environment it is run in.
The problem is, if I initialize this `TestTasks` class like this:

```
internal class TestClass : BaseTestClass
{
    private TestTasks Tasks { get; } = new TestTasks();
}
```

it cannot find and read the variable (I put a debug statement in `TestTasks` constructor to see if it can read the variable from there during instantiation).

However, if I do it like this (and which I really want to avoid):

```
internal class TestClass : BaseTestClass
{
    private TestTasks Tasks => new TestTasks();
}
```

it works.

Why it cannot read the variable when initialized the first way? And what can I do to pass some value globally from the one time setup in base class to all derived test classes?

Comment: second one is not a property initialization. It's a short way to write `private TestTasks Tasks { get { return new TestTasks(); } }`

Comment: I know what it is, but how does it answer my question about the variables not being read by the `TestTasks` constructor?

Comment: @YMM check my updated answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private TestTasks Tasks => new TestTasks();
```

is equivalent of

```
private TestTasks Tasks { get { return new TestTasks(); } }
```

thus, it'll create a new object of `TestTasks` each time you try to get that

whereas

```
private TestTasks Tasks { get; } = new TestTasks();
```

Will create the list once, and the `TestTasks` constructor will be called even **Before** the `TestClass` object constructor (and before your `OneTimeSetup` member method), thus it'll be called before the call to set the environment variable.

I suggest that you initialize your `Tasks` property in another `OneTimeSetup` method **OR** (maybe) you could make your `InitializeBaseSuite` method static, which should make it run before the property initialization?

Comment: I ended up making `Tasks` property protected in the base class and assigning a value to it in `OneTimeSetup` there. The environment variable is also set in the same method, before the property assignment. This way it works just like I need it.